# Value showing empty in browser , but its available in Database

Tags: php

Once we click on Download button, we are trying to download complete order details in pdf.... here **100452121** is orderid, **xpress** is shipping name & **14104918100111** is tracking id....

we set conditions that if tracking_id is empty, than it should `echo 0` but we are getting **zero** [0] even when tracking_id available for the order....

[image][image]

**Shippinglabel.php**  [Full code in pastebin](https://pastebin.com/tiGD8P7E)

```
<td><?php echo $orderrecords[$k]["order_id"]; ?><br/>
<?php
if ($st == 1) {
    if ($orderrecords[$k]["tracking_id"] == '') {       
?>

    <input type="button" name="shipment" id="xpress" value="xpress" 
    onclick="createshipment('<?php echo $orderrecords[$k]["order_id"];?>')" />

<?php
}
}
?>

<?php
if ($orderrecords[$k]["tracking_id"] != '' && $orderrecords[$k]["shipping_name"] == 'xpress')
{
?>

    <a target="_blank"
    href="http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com/ecom1/xpress/xpressdownload.php?orderId=<?php
    echo $orderrecords[$k]["order_id"];?>" 
    id="pdfdownload" >

    <input type="button" name="shipment" value="DOWNLOAD" /></a>
<?php
}
?>
</td>
```

**createshipment**

```
function createshipment(orderid)
    {    
      var assignee='<?php echo $_SESSION['login_user']?>';
      alert(orderid);
      $.ajax({
        url: "xpressshipment.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:'orderid='+orderid+'&assignee='+assignee,
        success: function(data){
          if(data==1)
          {
            $("#pdfdownload").show();

          }         
          if(data==0){alert("First Enter Tracking Id.");}
          window.location ="http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com/ecom1/xpress/xpressdownload.php?orderId="+orderid;

        }
      });
    }
```

**xpressshipment.php**   [Full code in pastebin](https://pastebin.com/yFnxCyEV)

```
<?php

$data = 
array (
'AirWayBillNO' => $resultc[0]['awb'],
);

if($res->AddManifestDetails[0]->ReturnMessage=='successful')
{
    $sqli="update  do_order set tracking_id='".$resultc[0]['awb']."',shipping_name='xpress' where order_id='".$order_id."'";
    $resulti=$db_handle->executeUpdate($sqli);
}

?>
```

**xpressdownload.php**  [Full code in pastebin](https://pastebin.com/qD0uV4Wg)

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['orderId']) && $_GET['orderId']!='')
{
  $orderid=$_GET['orderId']; 
}
else
{
   echo 2;
}
$orderid='';

$sqlorder = "SELECT tracking_id,order_id from do_order where order_id='".$orderid."' limit 1";
$resultdoorder = $db_handle->runSelectQuerys($sqlorder);
if($resultdoorder['tracking_id']=='')
{
  echo 0;
  //var_dump("tracking_id");
}
```

**var_dump("tracking_id");** gave **string(11) "tracking_id"** as result....

please let me know if you need more details....

please help me to find solution....

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In file xpressdownload.php you defined variable $orderid incorrectly.

```
if(isset($_GET['orderId']) && $_GET['orderId']!='')
{
    $orderid=$_GET['orderId']; 
}
else
{
   echo 2;
}
$orderid='';
```

First, you are checking whether $_GET['orderId'] exists and if yes, you give the value of $_GET['orderId'] to $orderid. This is correct.
But after the if... else block you give the $orderid the '' value. So in every case the $orderid has the null value and you sql query is not returning the record. You have to remove the line $orderid=''; or move it before the if statement.

Comment: Ok, add new questions, I will try to help you.

Comment: This question is answered so you should add a new question if you have any new issues but i suggest you give them a try yourself first before posting here.